# Ansible is stop executing the tasks randomly without any error

Tags: jenkins, ansible

We are running an automated job in Jenkins that triggers an ansible playbook. However the playbook execution works 80% of the time, but sometimes it stops randomly at some tasks(hung) without any error as shown below

```
TASK [Install utilities like vim, mlocate etc.] ***************
changed: [192.0.100.30]
changed: [192.0.100.27]
```

It does not get stopped at the same task. It is getting stopped randomly at random points!!

I am unable to reproduce this issue if I execute it manually.

Comment: Can you provide the playbook, name the task where it is running, as well the time after which it looks like hanging? Furthermore, can you describe from what kind of environment you are triggered the playbook and how do you this?

Comment: Basically, this playbook is triggered from Jenkins Job which eventually executes on Controller node.  the environment is **RHEL 8.4** with **4CPU,8GB,30GBHDD** (controller and the remote hosts ).  The usual time of execution for this playbook will be less than 5min during normal execution.   Linke for Playbook [link](https://github.com/anand3200/anand3200/blob/main/Test_Playbook.yml)

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue I have faced earlier, this could be due to specific host might be hung or high on resource utilisation, in this case ansible task will be in queue and sometimes in hung state for that host.

Whenever such situation re-occurs, then immediately check the host health on which ansible is trying to apply the playbook.